# Determine at runtime if a service should be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a configuration which state if a service should be constructed or not.
In my class I'm injecting an `IEnumerable<IMyServiceInterface>` of that service.
But instead of getting an empty `IEnumerable<IMyServiceInterface>` with my code, I'm getting one filled with null values.

This is the code in my `Startup` class

```
services.AddScoped<IMyServiceInterface, MyService>(provider =>
{
    var options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyOptions>>();
    if (!options.Value.DisableService)
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyOptions>(provider);

    return default;
});
```

I do not want to pass the Configuration instance to the method to determine of the service should be added in the first place. This should be done at runtime.

I also want to avoid to register something like `IMyServiceFactory` which would look like this because I want to keep this transparent to the consumer and not force the class to request `IMyServiceFactory` instead of just `IEnumerable<IMyServiceInterface>`.

```
public IEnumerable<IMyServiceInterface> GetMyServices();
```

Can this be done somehow with the onboard Dependency injection?

Comment: Based on your stated limitations, then  `Can this be done somehow with the onboard Dependency injection?` Short answer: NO.

Comment: Longer answer: If you register it and have it return null then you get what you are already experiencing. If you do not register it but still have it as a dependency then you will get an exception about not being able to resolve the service. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If I do not register it and request an `IEnumerable` of it, it will simply be empty and no exception will be thrown. That's, what I was looking for.